# Connect two VirtualBox machines in a network

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I would like to connect two VirtualBox machines with Ubuntu in one network. I used to do something very similar using Qemu. I created two tap interfaces on the host that next was added to one bridge. In the next step I was running virtual machines attached to these tap interfaces. When I assigned IP addresses on Qemu interfaces, I was able to ping between these two virtual machines. I would like to do the same with VirtualBox machines. In Setting->Network I set Attached to: Bridged Adapter and Name set to my host tap. Next, I set IP addresses on guest interfaces, in the same network, but when I try to ping between the machines I get the following error:

```
PING 10.111.1.2 (10.111.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.111.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.111.1.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Do you have any idea where I am doing a mistake? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but you may need IP forwarding enabled. But would it not make more sense to connect them over an internal network that isn't visible outside of VirtualBox? Why connect them by the host's network?

Comment: @Kusalananda  My knowledge about networking is very poor. I just need to have two VirtualBox virtual machines connected in one network. The way described in the question is the only one I know because I tested it with Qemu. I am aware  that this may not be the best way.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal

Comment: @Kusalananda your link looks nice, thank you.

Comment: If nobody else writes this up as a proper answer, with an example, I might try to get back to it tomorrow. It's currently very late in my time-zone.